# How does the にして work here?

Tags: meaning, usage

> 学園付きの聖職者**にして**、委員会の顧問、xから、呼び出しのメールが来たのは今朝のこと

I read that

> adj + にして + adj

or

> noun + にして + noun

That in this case the にして has the meaning of "and / also"

In that case does this mean

> It was this morning that I received a mail that called me out from X who is the advisor of the committee and the clergy of the school

Answer (score 4, accepted):

にして can be used to combine two nouns and it means "and". Unlike "also", it puts the equal weight on both sides. It doesn't work with adjectives, ant it has a pinch of formality in it. It's usually not used in speaking Japanese.